# Django view foreign key in a backward relationship

Tags: django, django-views

I have those models :

Each student have a personal teacher :

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=200, default='', blank=True)
    group= models.CharField(max_length=200, default='', blank=True)
    teacher= models.ForeignKey(Teacher, null=True, blank=True)
    session = models.IntegerField(default=99, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

A teacher can teach at one, two, three, fours sessions.

```
class Teacher(Employe):
    ...
    session1 = models.NullBooleanField(default='', blank=True)
    session2 = models.NullBooleanField(default='', blank=True)
    session3 = models.NullBooleanField(default='', blank=True)
    session4 = models.NullBooleanField(default='', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Each classroom only have one teacher for that particular session.

```
class Classroom(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='', blank=True)
    teacherSession1 = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, null=True, blank=True, related_name='S1')
    teacherSession2 = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, null=True, blank=True, related_name='S2')
    teacherSession3 = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, null=True, blank=True, related_name='S3')
    teacherSession4 = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, null=True, blank=True, related_name='S4')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code
```

I want to build a query that would output something like that :

Student name, Student group, Classroom (for session 1 to 4)

So far I have came up with this, but I struggle at getting the classroom code.

```
def list_student_plan(session):
    my_list = Student.objects.values('name', 'group', 'teacher__name').filter(Q(session=session))
    return my_list
```

Comment: Do teachers teach different classes are they all the same? eg.) would the teacher have the same "code" for each of their classes?

Comment: I would create a new table (model) called 'sessions' which links the teacher, the code and the group all together through foreign keys.

Comment: A teacher have the same class code for a session. He can have a different classroom, or have the same code in a different session (if he teach in multiple sessions). The groups are not related to a teacher in particular, ie : Teachers have multiples students in each groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my recommend models

Groups

```
class Groups(models.Model):

    name    = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description   = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Student Model

```
class Student(models.Model):

    name    = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='', blank=True)
    group   = models.ForeignKey(Groups, null=True, blank=True, unique=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Code Model

```
class Code(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     code = models.CharField(max_length=25)
     description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Teacher Model

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     code = models.ForeignKey(Code, unique=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name + " " + self.code.name
```

Sessions

```
class Sessions(Employe):
     teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, unique=False)
     student = models.ForeignKey(Student, unique=False)
     session = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.teacher.name + ' ' + self.student.name
```

Now with "Sessions" will help you better manage, where session would contain a value
between 1-4 ( and possible more - imagine if you added an extra period to the day ). With teacher you will get a code, you can have multiple teachers with multiple codes, or the same teacher with multiple codes. I hope this gets you in the right direction and this in my opinion is a much cleaner way to approach this problem, let me know if you have any issues and I will add more details.

Comment: You may also create a "code" model if multiple teachers will teach the same class.

Comment: Is there another way ? I can do a raw SQL request and its working. I just want to know if I can use the api/orm to this more elegantly.

It adds steps and clicks to the people who manages the students and have to go between additional models to create and assign/check informations. There is a lot of informations in students and teacher models I omitted. Its gonna break most of my views/stats plus group assignments for group teachers etc etc

Perhaps I can try on a fork of my project.

Comment: Jody's schema makes significantly more sense. `Classroom` having `Teacher`s for each session, and then those `Teacher`s having boolean fields for each session makes no sense. You could most likely replicate your current workflow for the users on the front end, while using Jody's more elegant schema on the back end.

Comment: The solution is good for a school system but its way off for me. The models are not what you think, and its probably a language barrier issue on my side. The models are translated and it is not really a school. The Student/Teacher thing was to simplify the question, I guess I failed to represent the problem in a good way. Currently, I am able to get the "Classroom" this with a SQL request, my question is more related to the ORM.

Comment: I tried! I understand not wanting to post real world schemes but the practice would still be identical even if you changed it. It just makes more sense to connect data that way ( at least in my opinion ) if you want you can email jody(a)careerextender.com and I will see if I can help you.